# ASP.Net core project hosting on service fabric dos not start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric

We try to host an ASP.Net core MVC RC1 DNX project on Service Fabric. The deployment works but the project is not starting. According to our log it seems service fabric cannot find the startup class and create an instance. We downloaded a demo project that works fine, but we cannot bring our project up and running. We cannot see any peace of helpful log information. Not in event log, service fabric log stream or with visual studio debug prompt. Is there anything we can do to enable more debug information. What could be wrong on our configuration, or project setup? This are the Key parts of our project:

ServiceManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="WebPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="WebType" >
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="__GeneratedServiceType__">
          <GeneratedNames xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <DefaultService Name="WebTypeService" />
            <ServiceEndpoint Name="WebTypeEndpoint" />
          </GeneratedNames>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>

  <CodePackage Name="C" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin\dnx.exe</Program>
        <Arguments>--appbase approot\src\Sportflash.Web Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel</Arguments>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048" />
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="WebTypeEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="5000" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Sportflash.Web.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "angular-signalr-hub.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped": "0.6.7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Globalization.CultureInfoCache": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Localization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Localization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",    
    "jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped": "2.8.8",
    "signalr.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped": "0.2.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis": "1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01"
  },

  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-Sportflash.Web-f067f2f7-086e-4a52-88ea-a7317d1b11e8",

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "PackageRoot"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "PackageRoot",    
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install" ]
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Comment: Try to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832635/path-too-long-when-publishing-asp-net-5-from-visual-studio-2015

Comment: If the deployment is good, can you at least see the service in the browser when you open the Service Fabric explorer? It is not there, then that means it was not really deployed.

Comment: I can see it in the service fabric explorer. And I can also see the code on the filesystem in the service fabric folder at the place you would expect. I can even start the application at the place where Service Fabric deploys it with the usual web command.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to explore this example on [GitHub](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting).

This example demonstrates how ASP.NET Core can be used in a communication listener of stateless/stateful services.

**This example is updated to use `dotnet` cli.**

There are 2 different branches `dnx` and `dotnetcli`. `dnx` branch can be used inside Visual Studio.